Can't setState inside useEffect
Assume that i have an access token in local storage.
I need to check if a user is authenticated to access some url (/protected) for example
so i have a provider to provide authUser
Component wraps the protected component:
const Authenticated = ({ children }) => {
  const { authUser } = useAuthContext();
  if (!authUser) {
    console.log(authUser);
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  return children;
};
export default Authenticated;

My Provider:
const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const token = accessToken.getAccessToken();
    if (token) {
      CustomAxios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user")
        .then((res) => {
         setAuthUser(res.data.user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("API error:", error);
          setAuthUser(null);
        });
    }
  }, []);

Im sure that the the res.data.user from CustomAxios is correct and there is no error;
The problem here is **setAuthUser **not working, i still get null for authUser ( i set breakpoint after **setAuthUser **to check)
help me to fix and explain

Calling setAuthUser only changes what authUser will be on the next render. It has no effect on the variable from this render. If you would like to verify that the component rerendered with a new value, put your breakpoint in the body of the component (eg, after the line that calls useState)

Your issue is likely related to the asynchronous nature of useEffect and setAuthUser. When setAuthUser is called, React schedules an update, but it doesn't immediately update the value of authUser. This means that if you're checking the value of authUser immediately after setAuthUser, it might still be null at that moment. However, this does not imply setAuthUser isn't working—it just hasn't been updated yet.
If you want to verify that setAuthUser is actually setting the value, you can add some logging after the state update in a useEffect that listens for changes to authUser.
const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = accessToken.getAccessToken();
    if (token) {
      CustomAxios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user")
        .then((res) => {
          setAuthUser(res.data.user);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("API error:", error);
          setAuthUser(null);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("authUser updated:", authUser);
  }, [authUser]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

Hope this will help you
